# Stepper motor isn't running with Raspberry pi 4 and drv8825

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, motordriver

I am trying to use a Raspberry Pi 4 with a Nima 17 stepper motor using the DRV8825 driver. The motor has 200 steps per revolution, and I am using the following code:

```py
from time import sleep
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

DIR = 19   # Direction GPIO Pin
STEP = 26  # Step GPIO Pin
CW = 1     # Clockwise Rotation
CCW = 0    # Counterclockwise Rotation
SPR = 200   # Steps per Revolution (360 / 7.5)

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(DIR, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(STEP, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(DIR, CW)

step_count = SPR
delay = 0.005

for x in range(step_count):
    GPIO.output(STEP, GPIO.HIGH)
    sleep(delay)
    print('rot')
    GPIO.output(STEP, GPIO.LOW)
    print('stop')
    sleep(delay)

sleep(.5)
GPIO.output(DIR, CCW)
for x in range(step_count):
    GPIO.output(STEP, GPIO.HIGH)
    print('rot-')
    sleep(delay)
    GPIO.output(STEP, GPIO.LOW)
    print('stop-')
    sleep(delay)

GPIO.cleanup()
```

However, the motor keeps vibrating in both directions and won't work at all. I verified the direction is correct, and I am following the schematic shown below:

[image]

I am not currently connecting the m0, m1, m2 pins.

Comment: How fast as these vibrations? The code as written would send 200 pulses at .005 second increments in one direction for a total spin of 2 seconds, and then flips the direction and pulses in the opposite direction for 2 seconds. Also, are you certain that you have the right GPIO numbers? A raspberry 4 pin diagram I am looking at suggests that physical pins 38 and 40 (`DIR` and `STEP`) are GPIO 20 and 21.

Comment: @JNevill thank you for your response I'm sure that I used the right gpio numbers because I used the BCM layout which lead to 19 As direction PIN and 26 as step. also my motor has a step angle of 1.8° so 360÷1.8 is 200 also for the delay one second divided by 200 is .005

Comment: I agree with your calculations on step angle and the resulting math. The motor, with this code, should turn CW for 2 seconds (.005s between HIGH and LOW and then a .005s pause before the next iteration), then it should do the same CCW. The pin map I was looking at was from this site, https://www.etechnophiles.com/raspberry-pi-4-gpio-pinout-specifications-and-schematic/ the picture you have posted is pretty tiny/blurry so I'm not sure if the two maps match up, which led me to suggesting to double check the GPIO numbering you are using.

Comment: I do think your code is correct. I wonder if this same question may yield more help over at https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ where folks that answer can speak to both the programming and the physical set up to help troubleshoot further.